# Creating two messenger bots for one page

Tags: bots, messenger

Can I create two messenger bots (setting web hook for one) and using these bots? I need first bot for original purpose and the second one for contact center operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, one Facebook Page may have 10 apps installed. So, you can consider a bot as a 1 app. It is possible to have 10 bots per page currently(23/Jul/2017)